# [node.js][SQL] cannot connect to SQL server - Error: Handshake inactivity timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

Here's the node JS code I'm using:

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql');

const pool = createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "TEST",
    port: 3306,
    password: "TEST",
    database: "TestDB",
    connectionLimit: 10
});
pool.query(`select * from dbo.TestPlans`, function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    return console.log(result);
});
```

And this is the result I get:
[image]

Here's what I've done so far:

- I've enabled TCP/IP in my SQL server manager
- Manually set the TCP Port to 3306 in my SQL server manager
- Ensured that "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" is enabled through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- Ensured that the login "TEST" is capable of logging in through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with the "SQL Server Authentication" Authentication type

Changing the port number will give me a different error:
[image]

And using the first example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp) results in the program hanging.

I'm unsure what to look at at this point, is there a configuration I need to change in my SQL database to enable connections via node?

Comment: You say SQL Server, but have added a <mysql> tag. Are you using both here?

Comment: @jarlh Hello, it is an SQL server, but I added the mysql tag because that is the package I am using in node, sorry if that is confusing

Comment: MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server are completely different database products, use completely different network protocols and require completely different client libraries. Which one are you actually using? Just as you cannot access MySQL using the [`mssql` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql), you cannot access Microsoft SQL Servers using the [`mysql` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You are my life saver. Pivoted to using "tedious" and after a bit more head-smashing, I was able to get it to work. If I could trebuchet you some coffee, I would, TYSM